# Django: Joining on fields other than IDs (Using a date field in one model to pull data from a second model)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm attempting to use Django to build a simple website. I have a set of blog posts that have a date field attached to indicate the day they were published. I have a table that contains a list of dates and temperatures. On each post, I would like to display the temperature on the day it was published.

The two models are as follows:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
text = models.TextField()
date = models.DateField()

class Temperature(models.Model):
date = models.DateField()
temperature = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to be able to reference the temperature field from the second table using the date field from the first. Is this possible?

In SQL, this is a simple query. I would do the following:

```
Select temperature from Temperature t join Post p on t.date = p.date
```

I think I really have two questions:

1. Is it possible to brute force this, even if it's not best practice? I've googled a lot and tried using raw sql and objects.extra, but can't get them to do what I want. I'm also wary of relying on them for the long haul.
2. Since this seems to be a simple task, it seems likely that I'm overcomplicating it by having my models set up sub-optimally. Is there something I'm missing about how I should design my models? That is, what's the best practice for doing something like this? (I've successfully pulled the temperature into my blog post by using a foreign key in the Temperature model. But if I go that route, I don't see how I could easily make sure that my temperature dates get the correct foreign key assigned to them so that the temperature date maps to the correct post date.)

Answer (score 1):

There will likely be better answers than this one, but I'll throw in my 2¢ anyway.

You could try a property inside the Post model that returns the temperature:

```
@property
def temperature(self):
    try:
        return Temperature.objects.values_list('temperature',flat=True).get(date=self.date)
    except:
        return None
```

(code not tested)

Comment: I tested this and it works, with one exception. I don't think you can use "flat=True" with values. I think it only works with values_list. See here: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

About your Models:

If you will be displaying the temperature in a Post list (a list of Posts with their temperatures), then maybe it will be simpler to code and a faster query to just add a temperature field to your Post model.

You can keep the Temperature model. Then:

1. Assuming you have the temperature data already present in you Temperature model at the time of Post instance creation, you can fill that new field in a [custom save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).
2. If you get temperature data after Post creation, you cann fill in that new temperature field through a background job (maybe triggered by crontab or similar).

Sometimes database orthogonality (not repeating info in many tables) is not the best strategy. Just something to think about, depending on how often you will be querying the Post models and how simple you want to keep that query code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a basic approach to solve the problem

```
post_dates        = Post.objects.all().values('date')
result_temprature = Temperature.objects.filter(date__in = post_dates).values('temperature')
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries could be your friend here. Something like the following should work:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

temps = Temperature.objects.filter(date=OuterRef('date'))
posts = Post.objects.annotate(temperature=Subquery(temps.values('temperature')[:1]))
for post in posts:
    temperature = post.temperature
```

Then you can just iterate through posts and access the temperature off each post instance